# Site speed and memory tester?

Tags: php, performance

I am just searching for a freeware for windows, that accesses my page several times and gives me the average time to load (and if possible, the memory consumption). I need this because I am releasing a new version of my project and want to figure out how the loading time decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring memory consumption, Apache's "[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)" should do the trick. You can then monitor memory consumption on the server as `ab` is running.

Answer (score 0):

you could use apache benchmark (ab) ut should be included in xampp

Answer (score 0):

You could add [PHP Debug](http://www.php-debug.com) to your project, to run only on non-live environments (or for selected live users). This allows you to add debug statements to see where the bottleneck is for each page - initialisation, big queries, CPU-intensive tasks, etc. They are visible in a nice JavaScript debug toobar that floats on the top-right of your page.

I believe this is a stand-alone fork of that widget from symfony 1.